# Is Path-based Unoptimization Possible?

Tags: windows-server-2016, storage-spaces, deduplication

I have a deduplicated volume in Windows Server 2016 that some software is having problems dealing with.

Specifically, Matlab 2015 and older couldn't read deduplicated files, and while updating to a current version allowed for the files to be read, much recoding was required to restore functionality. Recoding is incomplete, and it will be more cost-effective to undo the deduplication.

The dedupcliation savings is greater than the amount of free space by a number of free space by nearly 7 TB, and the only method of undoing deduplication is to use the `Unoptimization` job type of [**`Start-DedupJob`**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/deduplication/Start-DedupJob?view=win10-ps). But it would run against the entire volume, so I would just like to de-deduplicate the current active set of working data and leave the remaining to rest in place until more capacity is added.

Besides using a method to make the data "new", like copying it to an off-volume location and then back again, is there a a way to de-deduplate a certain folder rather than an entire volume?